# How to align my HTML page components?

Tags: html, css

I want my page to output like this:
[image]

But instead it comes out like this:
[image]

What can you propose I should do? The code is template and CSS:

```
BODY {background-image: url(/welcome/static/images/register_top2.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; }
#content {
  width: 700px ;
  margin: 180  auto;

}
#content-container {
  width: 700px ;
  margin-left: 180px;  
}
#image-logo {
  float: right;
}
.has_errors { border: 1px solid #ff0000 }
.errors {color: #ff0000;}

      <!DOCTYPE hml>
                        <html>
                                <head>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/welcome/static/css/register.css"/>

                                <STYLE TYPE="text/css">



</STYLE> 


                                        <title>{% trans %}Register new distributor{% endtrans %}</title>      <script type="text/javascript" src="/welcome/static/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/welcome/static/js/jquery.popupWindow.js"></script>
                                </head>
                                <body>  

<div id="content"><img src="/welcome/static/images/reg-reg3.gif">
  <div id="content-container">







                                <form action="{{action}}" method="post">

                                               <table><tr><td>

                                                 <label>{% trans %}Soc security number{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>{{ form.soc_sec(size='10', maxlength='10')}}({% trans %}YYMMDDXXXX{% endtrans %})</td></tr>

                                                {% if form.soc_sec.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.soc_sec.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

                                                <tr><td>

 <label for="start">{% trans %}Your sponsor's ID{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>

                         <input id="log1" {% if form.sponsor_id.errors %}class="has_errors "{% endif %} maxlength="3" name="sponsor_id-log1" size="3" type="text" value="{% if form.sponsor_id.log1.data %}{{form.sponsor_id.log1.data}}{% endif %}" />

                       <input id="log2" {% if form.sponsor_id.errors %}class="has_errors "{% endif %} maxlength="3" name="sponsor_id-log2" size="3" type="text" value="{% if form.sponsor_id.log2.data %}{{form.sponsor_id.log2.data}}{% endif %}" />
                        <input id="log3" {% if form.sponsor_id.errors %}class="has_errors "{% endif %} maxlength="3" name="sponsor_id-log3" size="3" type="text" value="{% if form.sponsor_id.log3.data %}{{form.sponsor_id.log3.data}}{% endif %}" />
               <input id="log4" {% if form.sponsor_id.errors %}class="has_errors "{% endif %} maxlength="3" name="sponsor_id-log4" size="3" type="text" value="{% if form.sponsor_id.log4.data %}{{form.sponsor_id.log4.data}}{% endif %}" />

               (<a class="open_dialog" href="/static/sponsor-id.html">{% trans %}What is a sponsor ID{% endtrans %}?</a>)</td><td></tr>


{% if form.sponsor_id.log1.errors %}


<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.sponsor_id.log1.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

<tr><td>
                                                <label>Email</label></td><td> {{ form.email(size='22', maxlength='60')}}  </td></tr>

{% if form.email.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.email.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}



<tr><td>
 <label>{% trans %}First name{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>{{ form.firstname(size='22', maxlength='60')}}</td></tr>

{% if form.firstname.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.firstname.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

<tr><td>
 <label>{% trans %}Last name{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>{{ form.lastname(size='22', maxlength='60')}}</td></tr>

{% if form.lastname.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.lastname.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

<tr>
 <td>
 <label>{% trans %}Address{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>{{ form.address(size='22', maxlength='60')}}</td></tr>

{% if form.address.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.address.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

<tr><td>
<label>{% trans %}Zip code{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>{{ form.zipcode(size='22', maxlength='60')}}</td></tr>

{% if form.zipcode.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.zipcode.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

<tr><td>
<label>{% trans %}City{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>{{ form.city(size='22', maxlength='60')}}</td></tr>

{% if form.city.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.city.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

<tr><td>
<label>{% trans %}Phone{% endtrans %}</label></td><td>{{ form.phone(size='22', maxlength='60')}}</td></tr>

{% if form.phone.errors %}<tr><td></td><td> <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.phone.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div></td></tr>
    {% endif %}

</table>


                                        <button>{% trans %}Next{% endtrans %}</button>
                                </form> </div>
 <img id="image-logo" src="/welcome/static/images/snabbreg002.jpg" />

</div><script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.open_dialog').popupWindow({ 
height:500, 
width:700, 
top:325, 
left:400 
}); 
</script>
</body>
                        </html>
```

Comment: View it on a lower resolution monitor! (JK)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried adding a `background-position: center top`?

Answer (score 1):

As the above poster said. His answer is correct. Here is how I would mark it up. Actually, I just got Zen Coding for Gedit3 and I wanted to see all the HTML appear really fast :) .  I use HTML5 markup now, but I just did it via div style as most everyone is custom to. I took the time out at a later date to provide additional information as per the accepted answer.

```
#header {
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
vertical-align: top;
background-image: url('/foo/bar.png')
}

.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
          <title></title>
      </head>
        <div id="page">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="logo"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div id="body">
                    <div class="content_wrapper">
                        <div class="body"></div>
                        <div class="col1"></div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </html>
```

- Check this out if you are new to css

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: OK. Thanks for the link and the info.